# DataNucleus multitenancy: change column type to long

Tags: jpa, multi-tenant, datanucleus, discriminator

DataNucleus multitenancy: how change discriminator column name and type to:

```
   tenantId Long
```

Default is: TENANT_ID String.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can (change the type), because the primary use-case in any multitenancy system would be to use a "name" for the tenant, and that's all I've ever tried. You can change the column name clearly since that is in [their documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/annotations.html#MultiTenant_Class).

You could try something like this (not tested)

```
@Entity
@MultiTenant(column="TENANT")
@Extension(key="multitenancy-jdbc-type", value="BIGINT")
public class TheClass
{
...
}
```

The "jdbc-type" 'value' would likely need to be the string form of any of the normal JDBC "Types" names ("BIGINT", "INTEGER", "TINYINT", "SMALLINT", etc).

Comment: looks OK with 'name' concept, logically